# Want to insert the autoincrement id in Mysql in my data field via react

Tags: mysql, reactjs, rest, axios, sql-delete

i have a mysql database with an autoincrement id field a data field created_on and edited_on field and i want to copy the autoincrement id from the field in my datafield aswell. my sql looks like this

`'5045',`           this is my autoincremented id

`{\"id\": \"21\", \"ip\": \"111.111.111.111\", \"age\": \"\", \"car\": \"\", \"name\": \"test2\", \"standort\": \"CR\"},`    this is my data field

`'2023-09-13 14:46:43',`   my created_on field

`NULL`   and the edited_on field

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import axios from "axios";
>
> const DeviceDelete = ({ deviceId, onDelete }) => {
> const handleDelete = async () => {
> try {
> await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/devices/${deviceId}`);
> onDelete(deviceId);
> catch (err) {
> console.log(err);
>             }
>         };
> return (
>         <div>
>             <i onClick={handleDelete} class="close icon"></i>
>         </div>);
>     };
>
> export default DeviceDelete;
>
> const handleDeviceDelete = async (deviceId) => {
> const updatedData = data.filter((item) => item.id !== deviceId);
> setData(updatedData);
>         };
> ```

the problem is that i think it will use the id from the datafield to delete the entry

[Sql looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBf9E.png)

PROBLEM SOLVED WITH THIS SOLUTION

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qfog.png)

Answer (score 1):

To set a column auto-increment you need to mention it while creating the table itself

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
)
```